# UI Path configuration and organization questions

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-robot, uipath-activity

UI Path configuration question

Dear all,
Just wanted to understand your take on these questions. Relative newbie here.

I have a parent workflow invoking 12-15 child workflows.

A)
The parent reads all configuration settings and passes those on to child processes.

This works well for ‘run time’ situations but when debugging or creating enhancements, it slows me down to wait for parent workflow to initialize and then wait for the 12th flow to get its turn.

I cannot run just the 12th one directly as it then does not have parent level configuration details.

Wondering what a decent configuration management approach is in this space. There’s global configuration that I need but also specific configuration for the individual flows.

B)
Second question is how people structure and manage largish projects - is it through chained workflows/sequences, one calling another.

C)
Third question is around credentials management for automation of websites with authentication (nearly everyone) - do you use the password field filler, but that doesn’t seem to work when promoting workflows across machines.

Thank you in advance for helping.

Agam

Comment: Don't have time to answer fully (and really you should only have one question in each post here, but for point A, I'd suggest you give each child process an argument `TESTMODE` and in each process, have a check that states if this parameter is set to `True` then exit with a success report.  This will speed up getting to your 12th process by effectively skipping over the preceding processes

Comment: Yes, thank you Dave. Will keep that in mind! Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A) The old versions of uipath studio were better for debugging... but you cannot use the latest packages with them. Personally I am using hardcoded values during the development and after the tests of the sequence I am connecting it with the arguments.

B) For a large projects I am trying to use as many small robots as I can - this helps me with the business errors and it is easier to be tested

C) it depends of the case but the most common combination for me is orchestrator\get/set credential\ and type secure text

Comment: "B) For a large projects I am trying to use as many small robots as I can - this helps me with the business errors and it is easier to be tested" -- Could you please elaborate on this - any best practices (file/workflow/sequence organization) or anything else there.

Answer (score 0):

IN UI path for project layout we are using three activities sequence , flowchart or state machine  , If you use flowchart you can avoid some of the workflows execution